# Phaser render only what's in the camera

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm building a large open world game with Phaser

My problem: Because of the many components, which all have to be rendered, the world gets very slow and eventually even stops working.

So I was thinking if you could just stop rendering them?

How can you achieve this and is there maybe an inbuilt method for this?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are actually not rendering when out of camera scope, but they are 'updating' (phaser calls `update` for every game object added to launched scene) on every frame.
You can preven calling `.update()` of game object by `setActive` method:  https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject-setActive